# How to dynamically adding items to the Fabric-ui-react GroupedList component while restoring the collapsed state of each group?

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I'm using the GroupList in a scenario where I dynamically add and remove items from the list.
To make this work, I use the react lifecycle event *componentWillReceiveProps* to update the component state. This works as intented and the list content updates, BUT in the process all groups are collapsed.

How can I make the GroupedList restore collapsed state for each group?
Or how can I manually do it?

Thanks.